# WPF dependency property: multiple frequent calls

Tags: wpf

I am calling a dependency property (DP) in a C# application to update the Graphics (DirectX based).
By mistake, I was invoking it two times from same function in view-model.

```
public List<IObj> ModifiedData
{
    get
    {
        return modifiedData;
    }

    set
    {
        if (modifiedData != value)
        {
            modifiedData = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ModifiedData);
        }
     }
  }
```

The first was call was not triggering the DP handler on target side(graphics).

Following is the DP handler:

```
public static DependencyProperty ModifiedDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   "ModifiedData",
   typeof(List<IObj>),
   typeof(MyRenderer),
   new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnModifiedDataUpdated)));

public List<IObj> ModifiedData
{
    get{ return (List<IObj>)this.GetValue(ModifiedDataProperty); }
    set{ this.SetValue(ModifiedDataProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnModifiedDataUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do work - but this is not called !
}
```

Then I commented out the second call(which was unnecessary) and first call started working.
It seems like the first call is interrupted, if system receives second call!

So my question is, how the dependency property/property handlers are supposed to work if it is called two times in a very short interval?

Comment: The handler is supposed to be invoked each time the value of the dependency property actually changes. Are you sure that you set it to a new value the first time?

Comment: @mm8 Yes. I am creating new List object every time. On debugging, it was going inside the view-model code and RaisePropertyChanged() was called, but the breakpoint on DP handler is not hit.

Comment: Please provide a repo if your issue when asking a queston: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve